# JavaScript promise .then() not waiting for first part to finish

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I was having some problem with promise in JavaScript.

```
// global array
var heatmapData1 = [];

function drawmap(mapData){
   let promiseKey = Promise.all(
      //use geocode to get lat lng, set promise to return marker object. This part is working so I never post the code
   );

  var addedMarkers = promiseKey.then(
    markers => Promise.all(
      // add the marker object returned and plot one by one onto map
      markers.map(marker => addMarker(marker))
    )
  // after finish plotting, get the completed array then draw heatmap
  ).then(plotHeatmap(heatmapData1);
 }

function addMarker(marker) {
    // so far everything here printed out result so my geocode part is working
    console.log(marker['lat'] + marker['lng'] + marker['branchName'] + marker['address'] + marker['total']);

    //one by one add marker onto map

    // add the marker one by one into global heatmap array
    heatmapData1.push({latitude: marker['lat'], longitude: marker['lng']}); 
    console.log('done add');
}

function plotHeatmap(heatmapData1){    
    console.log('go in');
    for(var i = 0; i < heatmapData1.length; i++){
        console.log('PLOT ' + heatmapData1[i].latitude + ' ' + heatmapData1[i].longitude);
    }
}
```

The problem now is the plotHeapmap method never wait for addMarker() to finish before executing. I chained a `.then()` there but it does not seem to work.

Is there any way to enforce that the `addedMarkers` part finish executing first before executing the `plotHeatmap`? Because I am populating the parameter for `plotHeatmap` inside `addMarkers(),` therefore I need that part finish execute first.

Comment: try using addedMarkers().$promise.then()

Comment: It's because you are calling the plotheatmap instead of wrapping it in a callback function. Do something like `.then( () => plotHeatmap(...) )`

Comment: why don't you try using async await ?

Comment: @lumio Lol. There's no such concept that you have to always wrap it up in a callback function. Please don't mislead the answers.

Comment: @Kamesh Should I replace the $promise with something else? Because I am getting Cannot read property '$promise' of undefined error message

Comment: @Kamesh ... so no callback function hm. But how would you prevent it from being executed before it is needed? ;)

Comment: @lumio The addMarker() will loop many times. Once finish execute all, then I proceed to plotHeatmap cause I am populating the parameter for plotHeatmap inside addMarker()

Comment: @EmmaHannah yes, your intentions are right. The problem is, that when you implement it like a function call it is called immediately and doesn't wait for `.then` to resolve. Someone posted an answer that should work :)

Comment: @EmmaHannah But why do you need a callback here. map function is already synchronous I think. So you just need to call the functions just after one another. I don't think your code needs promise. Can you tell any asynchronous task taking place here.

Comment: EmmaHannah ... @Kamesh is right here (now I know what you meant) - you don't really need a Promise here.

Comment: @Kamesh Because I am grabbing address from firebase, then I proceed to use geocode to get the lat lng. After that, then I need to plot them onto map. Without the promise, the plotting of marker will execute first before the geocode return the lat lng. Therefore, I plugged a promise there to enforce it to wait.

Comment: @Kamesh & lumio Thanks for the helps!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line `).then(plotHeatmap(heatmapData1);` lacks `)` right before the semicolon, but the problem is that `plotHeatmap` is executed immediately, I believe you need to write something like

```
).then(plotHeatmap);
```

to pass a function to `then`

Comment: Oh gosh I did not realized that the problem is just that :( Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Hey sorry but why is passing a parameter makes a different? Or the problem is due to the missing ')'?

Comment: When you write `then(plotHeatmap)` you pass `plotHeatmap` as an argument to the `then` function. When you write `then(plotHeatmap(something))` you pass to the `then` function result of the execution of `plotHeatmap(something)`